# Best way to communicate with telnet api from python?

Tags: python, python-3.x

I have a multi-room speaker system from Denon called Heos which I want to control by using python script. To communicate with the multi-room system I have to telnet to port 1255 on the device and send commands like this:

```
heos://player/set_play_state?pid=player_id&state=play_state
```

The response back is in json:

```
{
 "heos": {
 "command": " player/set_play_state ",
 "result": "success",
 "message": "pid='player_id'&state='play_state'"
 }
}
```

I have successfully used python telnet lib to send simple commands like this:

```
command = "heos://player/set_play_state?pid=player_id&state=play_state"
telnet.write(command.encode('ASCII') + b'\r\n')
```

But what is the best way to get the response back in a usable format? Loop with telnet.read_until? I want to result and message lines back to a clean variable.

This method with using telnet to communicate with api feels a bit dirty. Is it possible to use something else, for example socket?

Thanks in advance

The API/CLI is documented here: http://rn.dmglobal.com/euheos/HEOS_CLI_ProtocolSpecification.pdf

Comment: Why are you using `telnet` instead of an HTTP library like `requests`?

Comment: The CLI is listening on port 1255 with commands like heos://. I'm not sure if requests can be used in this way?

Comment: Sorry, I read that as `http` for some reason. You should be able to use the `urllib` library, though.

Comment: Does it close the connection after sending the response, or does it remain open for more commands?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

While it may be possible to use `loop_until()` here, it would depend on exactly how the response JSON is formatted, and it would probably be unwise to rely on it.

If the remote device closes the connection after sending the response, the easy way would be a simple

```
response = json.loads(telnet.read_all().decode())
```

If it remains open for more commands, then you'll instead need to keep receiving until you have a complete JSON object. Here's a possibility that just keeps trying to parse the JSON until it succeeds:

```
response = ''
while True:
    response += telnet.read_some().decode()
    try:
        response = json.loads(response)
        break
    except ValueError:
        pass
```

Either way, your result and message are `response['heos']['result']` and `response['heos']['message']`.

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion! The connection is not closed after the response but the JSON command response delimiter is "\r\n".

Comment: I tried your code example with read_some() and it worked perfectly! Thanks! Do you think this is the most effective way to do it?

Comment: @user1209325 Depends on how you measure "most effective", but this should be robust, and I don't know of a more concise way to detect when you have a valid JSON object.

Answer (score 0):

FWIW, here is my [GitHub repo](https://github.com/ping13/heospy) (inspired by [this repo](https://github.com/mrjohnsen/heos-python)) for controlling a HEOS speaker with Python. It uses a similar approach as the accepted result, but additionally waits if the HEOS player is busy.

```
def telnet_request(self, command, wait = True):
    """Execute a `command` and return the response(s)."""
    command = self.heosurl + command
    logging.debug("telnet request {}".format(command))
    self.telnet.write(command.encode('ASCII') + b'\r\n')
    response = b''
    while True:
        response += self.telnet.read_some()
        try:
            response = json.loads(response)
            if not wait:
                logging.debug("I accept the first response: {}".format(response))
                break
            # sometimes, I get a response with the message "under
            # process". I might want to wait here
            message = response.get("heos", {}).get("message", "")
            if "command under process" not in message:
                logging.debug("I assume this is the final response: {}".format(response))
                break
            logging.debug("Wait for the final response")
            response = b'' # forget this message
        except ValueError:
            # response is not a complete JSON object
            pass
        except TypeError:
            # response is not a complete JSON object
            pass

    if response.get("result") == "fail":
        logging.warn(response)
        return None

    return response
```